# Add custom header link in custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, header

I am trying to add custom header link, but it is not showing.

Comment: where you want to add custom link in header..?

Answer (score 0):

**To add custom Header Link :**

Create a default.xml file in the below path.

> app/code/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Add the Below Code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customlinkpath</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add link in main menu then please follow below steps

Create a default.xml file on below path

```
app/code/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Add below code

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="static_page_top_menu">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_page_top_menu</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Create new CMS block and add below code

```
<ul class="static-menu">
    <li class="level0 nav-5 last level-top ui-menu-item"><a class="level-top ui-corner-all" href="{{store direct_url=""}}">Custom Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please Add bellow css according to your design

```
.navigation ul.static-menu {
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: static;
}
.navigation ul.static-menu .level0  .level-top {
    border:0;
}
```